# jQuery - Sidebar that slides in, and keep the window width

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar, sliding

I've been trying to figure this out but I've not managed yet.. So I'm asking you for help!

What I want to do is: when the user clicks a button a sidebar is either shown or hidden. The content should follow, slide the same direction as the sidebar, and the user should not be able to see the y overflow.

This is basically what I want to do: http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/

Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: What have you attempted so far? It's best to include some markup showing you've made an attempt at doing this yourself so it doesn't look like you are asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: So basically this: http://jsfiddle.net/D3H68/

Comment: And I'm a newbie on Stackoverflow and will certainly have your tip about showing what I've done in mind next time I have a question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a button that will toggle the menu:

```
var menuEnabled = false;

$("button").click(function() {
    if (menuEnabled) {
        $("#left").css("display", "none");
        $("#content").css("margin-left", "0");
        menuEnabled = false;
    } else {
        $("#left").css("display", "block");
        $("#content").css("margin-left", "200px");
        menuEnabled = true;
    }
});
```

Full Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YwRSb/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer mrkou. This is pretty much what I already got, forgot to mention it.. But I want the content to move right when the sidebar is shown at the leftside, at the same time I don't want horizontal scroll enabled. How do I do that? Thanks again

Comment: No problem. I updated the fiddle. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The problem is that I'm still possible to scroll horizontal, do you know how to fix that? If you look at the example there is no possibility to show the sidebar by scrolling. Thanks!

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ Do you understand my problem? In the fiddle it works but not when I try it on my computer trough Chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35077/discussion-between-mrkou-and-user2362529)